# How to convert Specflow test results to Cucumber Messages format

Tags: npm, cucumber, specflow

My goal is to push Specflow [test results to CucumberStudio](https://studio.cucumber.io/cucumber-projects/246769/repo-branches/96495/settings/ci). The format should be [Cucumber Messages](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/messages), but when running the Specflow tests from the command line like this, I cannot get that 'logger' format.

```
dotnet test -r C:\Dev\ws\ProjectName\TestResults
```

I tried installing JunitXml.TestLogger using NuGet, to get that format in the hope that I can then convert it to Cucumber Messages.

```
dotnet test -r C:\Dev\ws\ProjectName\TestResults --logger:junit
```

Then I have tried to convert using [@cucumber/json-to-messages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cucumber/json-to-messages).

```
npm install -g @cucumber/json-to-messages
```

But I have not been able to successfully run the command as outlined in their Readme.

Running from PowerShell

```
cat .\TestResults\TestResults.xml | C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@cucumber\json-to-messages\bin\json-to-messages > my_report.messages
```

I am getting an error

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: 
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@cucumber\json-to-messages\bin\json-to-messages.
+ ... sults.xml | C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@cucumber ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Users\Admin\...son-to-messages:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantActivateDocumentInPipeline
```

The tools exist, but I am obviously struggling to use them correctly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you detail which Cucumber version you are using?

Comment: I'm using SpecFlow v3.6.23 (a .NET flavour of Cucumber)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should export to JSON, not JUnit for the converter to work properly. I haven't played with SpecFlow for a while, but I think SpecNuts (https://github.com/DonutReport/SpecNuts) would generate a JSON file that can be used by @cucumber/json-to-messages.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been looking into this, with a Specflow project targeted at .Net 5.0. Unfortunately SpecNuts hasn't been updated in 4 years from what I can tell, and migration of it to .Net 5.0 is a non-trivial task (currently SpecNuts appears to target .Net framework 4.6).